# Python sort Value list, then sort by value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, with a name as a key and a list containing scores as the value.

I'm trying to sort the lists in the values and then sort the whole dictionary by the values - making it so it's sorted by the highest score.

Here's the dictionary:

```
{'Dave_Wright': [10], 'Clara_Johnson': [9, 7], 'Amy_Kukri': [9, 8, 9], 'Eden_Jia': [10]}
```

I'm trying to use code I'v found from other places of stackoverflow, but I've not found a question specific to this yet.

```
print(d2)
d2 = sorted(d2.items(), key = itemgetter(1))
for key in d2:
    print(key, d2[key])
```

I'm probably making a mountain out of a molehill with this, but I am genuinely stumped.

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: what is `itemgetter`?

Comment: @Finwood: [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

Comment: nice, didn't know about that one :)

Answer (score 0):

Just `itemgetter(1)` will not do the sorting.  You need to write your own key for this:

```
def get_return(key_value):
    return list(sorted(key_value[1])), key_value[0]

d2 = sorted(d2.items(), key=get_return, reverse=True)

for key, value in d2:
    print(key, value)
```

[Here](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-sort-python-dictionaries-by-key-or-value/) is a helpful tutorial for sorting dictionaries by keys/values that was recommended by [spectre-d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5986225/spectre-d)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This will print the dictionary in the order you've specified (assuming that you meant highest-score first):

```
d = {'Dave_Wright': [10], 'Clara_Johnson': [9, 7], 'Amy_Kukri': [9, 8, 9], 'Eden_Jia': [10]}

print ('\n'.join(
    '{}, {}'.format(key, sorted(value, reverse=True))
    for key, value in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)))
```

Result:

```
Dave_Wright, [10]
Eden_Jia, [10]
Amy_Kukri, [9, 9, 8]
Clara_Johnson, [9, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries aren't usually sortable; though you can sort the key-value pairs in the dictionary.

```
for name, scores in sorted(d2.items(), key=lambda x: max(x[1]), reverse=True):
    print name, sorted(scores)  # reverse=True?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for l in d.values():
    l.sort(reverse=True) # this will sort the values in place(mutate the dict)
result = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
Out[518]:
[('Eden_Jia', [10]),
 ('Dave_Wright', [10]),
 ('Amy_Kukri', [9, 9, 8]),
 ('Clara_Johnson', [9, 7])]
```

Is this the output you expected?